# Python Pandas - Lambda apply keep initial format

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to transform this Series

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
df = pd.Series([["comic of book", "horror of movie"], ["dark", "dark french"]])
>> 0  [comic of book, horror of movie]
>> 1  [dark, dark french]
```

by removing `stopwords` and keeping only nouns (`NN` in `nltk`). I think the `apply` function is the best solution, however applying it directly to these texts generates a loss of information. I get this

```
df.apply(lambda x: [wrd for ing in x for wrd in word_tokenize(ing) if wrd not in stop_words])
0    [comic, book, horror, movie]
1            [dark, dark, french]
```

instead of

```
0    [comic book, horror movie]
1            [dark, dark french]
```

I miss something in the `for loop` and it separates each `bag of words` in unique `words` (maybe `apply` is not good here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rmsw(y):
    return ' '.join(set(y.split()) - stop_words)

pd.Series([[rmsw(y) for y in x] for x in df], df.index)

0    [comic book, horror movie]
1           [dark, dark french]
dtype: object
```

---

To maintain order and frequency

```
def rmsw(y):
    return ' '.join([w for w in y.split() if w not in stop_words])

pd.Series([[rmsw(y) for y in x] for x in df], df.index)
```

Comment: This changes the order of words because of `set` but it does the job !

Answer (score 1):

If performance is more important than elegance, a classic algorithm can do the trick.

The following code will never win a beauty contest, but it's about 350 - 400% more performant (on my ThinkPad) than the, admittedly, much nice list comprehension approach. The gap will grow with the size of your data set, as it's working in more primitive datatype (lists) and converts back to pandas in the end.

```
temp_list = list()

for serie in df:
    elements = list()
    for element in serie:
        for word in element.split():
            if word in stop_words:
                element = element.replace(f' {word} ', ' ')

        elements.append(element)

    temp_list.append(elements)

df = pd.Series(temp_list)
print(df)
```

The choice is your up to you :)

Comment: multiplying the `Series` by some factor, I find that this solution is time equivalent if not very little slower than the accepted answer !

Comment: That's not the results I get and it would make me surprised. The trick is to not perform a string operation (with join) for every element not containing a stop word. If you are iterating 10 times, there will be more jitter in the measurement than performance difference, if you run >1000 iterations you will see a clear difference where jitter is less of a dominant factor.